# Apply many update operators on the same array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a collection, I have an array field that I want to update with a whole new list using the following code:

```js
MyCollectionModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  _someId,
  {
    $pull: {
      arrField: { $nin: newListValues }
    },
    /* Either remove the old values as above, or unset the field:
    $unset: {
      arrField: 1
    },
    */
    $addToSet: {
      arrField: newListValues
    }
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

This ends with the error:
`Updating the path 'arrField' would create a conflict at 'arrField'`

Is there a way to override the value of the `arrField` in one shot without executing two separate requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite the field by simply passing the array without unsetting and trying to `addToSet`.

Example:

```js
const newListValues = ['I am a string inside an array.'];

MyCollectionModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  _someId,
  {
    arrField: newListValues
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

if `newListValues` is not an array, you'll need to set the new value to an array before trying to set it.

```js
const newListValues = 'I am a string';

MyCollectionModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  _someId,
  {
    arrField: [newListValues]
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right: a simple $set did the trick :)